# Group by columns and find IDs in both groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
id   | date      | year| cohort
17482| 2017-01-01| 2017| tier 1 
17482| 2017-01-01| 2017| tier 2
17483| 2017-01-01| 2017| tier 2 
17483| 2017-01-01| 2017| tier 2
```

I want to group by year and cohort and find the number of unique ids for each cohort per year. I use the following code

```
df.groupby(['year', 'cohort'])['id'].nunique().reset_index()
```

The output of the code is

year|cohort|id
2017|tier 1|400
2017|tier 2|600

However, there are only 500 unique ids in the year 2017. Therefore I want to find the IDs that are in both tier 1 and tier 2

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I just need a count of ids that have a row with cohort = tier 1 AND cohort = tier 2 in a given year. So in the example above the only ID 17482 is in both cohorts for 2017

Answer (score 1):

Question not clear. Please try and let us know. Happy to help further

```
df.groupby(['id','year','cohort']).size()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import numpy as np
df['new_col'] = df.groupby(['year', 'cohort','id']).transform('count')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
data_year_cohort = df.groupby(["id","year", "cohort"])["id"].count().reset_index(name="individual") 
count_unique = data_year_cohort.groupby(["id","year", "individual"])["id"].count().reset_index(name="cohorts_in_year")
request_matching_ids = count_unique.id.loc[(count_unique.cohorts_in_year == 2)]
len(request_matching_ids)
```

**Explanation**

There's two parts to the process.

Firstly, you want to group the data by ID, year and cohort to find each unique combination of those three.

Once you have that (second line of code), you can count these unique combinations from each ID and year. As there is two cohorts, a count of 2 will mean there is at least 1 'tier 1' also and at least 1 'tier 2' for the particular ID and year that show up in the resulting row(s).

You can then filter that final step if you'd like to only show the IDs with a count of 2 in the second step, which are the ones you're after based on your request.

And finally, as you specified in your follow up, you want a count of those IDs, which is as simple as using len() on the dataframe created in the third line of code.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment

> I just need a count of ids that have a row with cohort = tier 1 AND cohort = tier 2 in a given year. So in the example above the only ID 17482 is in both cohorts for 2017

is this what you wanted?

```
df[df['cohort'].isin(['tier 1','tier 2'])].groupby(['year','id']).agg('count')
```

Answer (score 0):

We do a pivot on `tier` column, indexed by `id` first, counting how many times each id appears in each tier, by id/year

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df.assign(count = 1), index = ['id','year'], columns='cohort', values='count', aggfunc = 'count')
```

this produces

```
cohort          tier 1  tier 2
id      year        
17482   2017    1.0     1.0
17483   2017    NaN     2.0
```

Now it is just a matter of reporting rows where both `tier 1` and `tier 2` are non NaN:

```
df2[(~df2['tier 1'].isna()) & (~df2['tier 2'].isna())]
```

output

```
    cohort      tier 1  tier 2
id      year        
17482   2017    1.0     1.0
```

then you can count them however you like it